# Android WINDOW_SERVICE: reorder floating windows

Tags: java, android, user-interface

My question is about reordering overlay windows created from `(WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)` routine. I search methods like "Bring to front" and "Send to back". The only solution I found for bringing to front is using

```
        windowManager.removeView(window);
        windowManager.addView(window, layout_parameters);
```

But this causes triggering `surfaceCreated()` and `surfaceDestroyed()` events for Surface I'm using in floating window. That isn't good for me. I would prefer having a function like `windowManager.replaceView(window)` but `WindowManager` hasn't the similar one.

Comment: Just to follow up, have you found a way around it? I'm also stuck trying to find a solution.

Comment: No, I am still using remove/addView workaround as I've described in the question.